# How to bind a WPF GUI value to reflect if an underlying value is a certain enum value

Tags: wpf, user-interface, binding, enums, viewmodel

I have a WPF application that is supposed to alert users about impending errors in a pump. There are three kinds of errors, which I have defined as an enum in a PumpErrorModel. This pumpErrorModel also knows which type of error is the most probable. This is exposed by my PumpErrorViewModel to the GUI, which has a label bound to the value of this most probable error, converted to a string. So far, so good.

```
// from MainWindow.xaml
<Label ... Content="{Binding LikelyError, Converter={StaticResource PumpErrorTypeToString}}" />

// from PumpErrorViewModel.cs
private PumpErrorModel.PumpErrorType likelyError;
public PumpErrorModel.PumpErrorType LikelyError {
    get { return likelyError; }
    private set { likelyError = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LikelyError"); } }
```

In my GUI I also have descriptions of each type of pump error, i.e one for each value of the enum. I would like to bind the background of each of these labels to the value of the most probable error type, so that when the most probable error type is "Explosions", then the label describing explosions has a red background, while the other labels have a white background.

```
// from MainWindow.xaml. I would like to bind the background of these
<Label Content="Likely Error: Explosions" />
<Label Content="Likely Error: More Explosions!" />
<Label Content="Likely Error: Rabbits!!!" />
```

I could make a boolean Property in the viewmodel for each type of error, that indicate if the probable error is of a specific type. I could then bind each of the label backgrounds to the corresponding properties. But it seems a bit messy to me, since I have to call RaisePropertyChanged on each of these extra in the setter of the original probable error property.

```
// proposed code in PumpErrorViewModel.cs
public bool IsRabbits { get { return LikelyError == PumpErrorModel.PumpErrorType.Rabbits; } };

// amended LikelyError setter
public PumpErrorModel.PumpErrorType LikelyError {
   get ...
   private set { likelyError = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged("LikelyError");
                 RaisePropertyChanged("IsRabbits"); } }

// proposed code in MainWindow.xaml
<Label Content="Likely Error: Rabbits!!!" BackGround="{Binding IsRabbits, Converter){StaticResource BoolToColor}}" />
```

If I do this, then I have a coupling between LikelyError and IsRabbits, that I am likely to forget whenever I add new error types and boolean properties. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good situation to use a child collection on your main view model. Each view model in that child collection would represent a single pump error type. Your view would then bind to that collection to list all potential pump errors and highlight the likely one. Here's our starting point for discussion below:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICollection<PumpErrorTypeViewModel> pumpErrorTypes;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.pumpErrorTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PumpErrorType))
            .Cast<PumpErrorType>()
            .Select(x => new PumpErrorTypeViewModel(x))
            .ToList();
    }

    pubilc ICollection<PumpErrorTypeViewModel> PumpErrorTypes
    {
        get { return this.pumpErrorTypes; }
    }


public class PumpErrorTypeViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly PumpErrorType type;

    public PumpErrorTypeViewModel(PumpErrorType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public PumpErrorType Type
    {
        get { return this.type; }
    }

    public string Display
    {
        // do whatever formatting you like here
        get { return string.Format("Likely Error: {0}", this.type); }
    }
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PumpErrorTypes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Display}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, to make the leap to coloring the background of the labels, we have a number of ways we could achieve this but the two most common would be:

1. `MainViewModel` could have a `LikelyError` property. `PumpErrorTypeViewModel` could take `MainViewModel` in its constructor and expose a `Background` property. It could listen to changes in `LikelyError` and invalidate its `Background` accordingly. This is a good fit for a reactive implementation (see ReactiveUI).
2. `PumpErrorViewModel` could expose an `IsLikely` property which, when set, invalidates its `Background` property. `MainViewModel` can loop through all `pumpErrorTypes` whenever `LikelyError` changes and update the `IsLikely` property on the child.

Either way, the view has one simple change:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Display}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>
```